# Как построить простую система прогнозирования временных рядов на C#?

Tags: c#

Решил написать простенькую программу для прогнозирования временного ряда. Что хочу от программы: данные тянутся из excel-файла, простой кнопочный интерфейс, на котором можно выбрать одну из нескольких моделей для прогнозирования временного ряда, построение графика и сохранение данных обратно в excel-файл.

Вопросы:

1.По какой логике строить приложение ? Какие технологии и инструменты применять на каком этапе ?

2.Как подтягивать данные в программу ? Из excel в БД, а потом уже из БД извлекать?

3.Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, материалы или статьи, с помощью которых я смог бы продвинуться в этом начинании.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1.Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какой логике строить приложение ? Какие технологии и инструменты применять на каком этапе ?

По той логике, что вам нужна. Технологии - Windows Forms ([раз](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/), [два](https://metanit.com/sharp/forms.php)) или WPF ([раз](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/designers/getting-started-with-wpf?view=vs-2019), [два](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/)). Инструменты - [Visual Studio 2019 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/community/)

> 1.Как подтягивать данные в программу ? Из excel в БД, а потом уже из бд я их извлекаю ?

Подтягивайте напрямую из Excel файла, пишите напрямую в Excel файл. [Раз](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet), [два](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)

> 2.Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, материалы или статьи, с помощью которых я смог бы продвинуться в этом начинании.

[Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/179763)

PS: Настоящий аналитик нумерует вопросы рядом фибоначчи? :)